# replace the number after # using cutoff and modify the column in multicolumn file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have file with multiple columns. each column onwards 4th column,has 2 parts a part before # and a part after #. If the number after # is >20, then I want to replace the # and the followed the number with null like 0|0#99 is becoming 0|0 as 99 > 20. If number followed by # is <20, then I want to replace the entire cell value with "./." like 0|0#14 is becoming "./.". If there isa dot after #, then it the value as it is like 0|0#. will be 0|0#. as it it.

input_file.txt. tab separated file I have

```
1   12345   A   T   0|0#.   0|0#.   0|0#14  0|0#.   0|0#.   0|0#20  0|0#15  0|0#40  0|0#99      
1   78906   C   T   0|0#99  0|0#.   0|0#10  0|0#.   0|0#45  0|0#20  0|0#95  0|0#78  0|0#99
```

Output > 20

```
1   12345   A   T   0|0#.   0|0#.   ./. 0|0#.   0|0#.   ./. ./. 0|0 0|0     
1   78906   C   T   0|0 0|0#.   ./  0|0#.   0|0 ./. 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

I tried following code but not getting desired output. Kindly help me to resolve this

```
awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $1 ~ /\#[>20]/ ) {print $0} else; {print"./."}}' input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For your limited input:

`sed 's%0|0#1*[0-9] %./. %g; s/0|0#[2-9][0-9] /0|0 /g' input_file.txt`

- It's important to find a character for the substitution that's not forward slash.
- `<20` is matched as `1*[0-9]`  (note trailing space)
- `>=20` is `[2-9][0-9]`
- glob replacement is used

Ack.  I see you say "tab separated." The paste into my system has spaces.- the spaces becomes tabs then:

`sed 's%0|0#1*[0-9]\t%./.\t%g; s/0|0#[2-9][0-9]\t/0|0\t/g' input_file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` command should do the trick:

```
awk -v cutoff=20 '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    { for (i=5; i<=NF; ++i)
          if ($i ~ /#[0-9]/) {
              sub(/.*#/, "", $i)
              $i = $i>cutoff ? "0|0" : "./."
          }
    } 1
' input_file.txt
```